# How to map specific record type from source to specific record type in target

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud, informatica-data-integration-hub

I am trying to find a way to migrate data from `Salesforce A` to `Salesfore B` Account data with specific conditions in place.

Source condition is `RecordType.Name= 'Customer Account' AND RecordType.Name='Partner Account'` and map with the targets `RecordType.Name= 'Client' AND RecordType.Name='Partner Data'`.

So when source record type is `Customer Account` then it should get inserted where Target's `RecordType.Name='Client'` . is there a way to filter data on target ?

[image]

Comment: use an expression like this `source A -> EXP -> Target B`. In the expression change the RecordType like this `IIF ( Record_Type ='Client partner', 'Client', IIF( Record_Type ='Partner', 'Partner Data'))`.

Comment: this is not I want, when Record tyoe in client partner is true then I want to insert records where the record type is equal to client in the destination.

Comment: hmm, i am nto able to understand the scenario. is it related to informatica the ETL tool ? Did you create any mapping ? can you pls show/screenshot it?